# arcgis server 10, vb.net add reference problems

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, web-mapping, vb.net, arcgis-web-adf

i am using 'arcgis server 10' and 'visual web developer 2010 express'. now, i opened a 'web mapping application' then wanted to 'add a reference' to 'esri arcmap object library 10.0' it says:

```
 A reference to 'ESRI ArcMap Object Library 10.0' could not be added.
 Converting the type library to a .NET assembly failed. No process is
 associated with this object.
```

it said the same for 'esri 3danalyst object library 10.0', 'esri geoanalyst object library 10.0', 'esri geostatisticalanalyst object library 10.0', 'esri spatialanalyst object library 10.0'...

but for this one it says:

```
 A reference to 'ESRI Display Object Library 10.0' could not be added.    
 Converting the type library to a .NET assembly failed. The type library
 importer encountered an error during type verification. Try importing
 without class members.
```

i tried this with target .net frameworks 3.5 and 4.0. plz can you explain how can i add these references successfully? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to make sure the ESRI AGS SDK is installed properly; you will want to use the 'Add ArcGIS Reference' (not sure of exact name, not at work pc) versus the usual add reference tool. This is because there are nested dependencies and how the DLLs are loaded that ESRI handles for you.
 This will get them all to load right. If you run the SDK installer, things should register to Visual Studio properly and you will see it in the context menus.